# java jvm crashes before running my program

Tags: java, performance, jvm, jvm-crash

My java JVM crashes before even it starts to run my program.

I am pretty confused as to why this happens.

My Java Hotspot logs are as under. Any help is highly appreciated.

Is this due to system running low on memory or someother bug that has been fixed recently in jvm.

```
#
# An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGBUS (0x7) at pc=0x00007f3db170885b, pid=6503, tid=1097546048
#
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (10.0-b23 mixed mode linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libc.so.6+0x7b85b]  memset+0xa5b
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread is native thread

siginfo:si_signo=SIGBUS: si_errno=0, si_code=2 (BUS_ADRERR), si_addr=0x00007f3db1f05000

Registers:
RAX=0x00007f3db1f05000, RBX=0x0000000000000003, RCX=0x0000000000000000, RDX=0x0000000000000000
RSP=0x00000000416b2e48, RBP=0x00000000416b2e80, RSI=0x0000000000000000, RDI=0x00007f3db1f05000
R8 =0x0000000000007f80, R9 =0x0000000000040000, R10=0x0000000000000000, R11=0x00007f3db17081d0
R12=0x00007f3db1f05000, R13=0x00000000401114f0, R14=0x00000000401114b0, R15=0x0000000000008000
RIP=0x00007f3db170885b, EFL=0x0000000000010206, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000006
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00000000416b2e48)
0x00000000416b2e48:   00007f3db1243be7 0000196740110d90
0x00000000416b2e58:   00007f3db1553218 0000000000008000
0x00000000416b2e68:   00007f3db1564720 00000000416b2fc0
0x00000000416b2e78:   00000000416b30e8 00000000416b2eb0
0x00000000416b2e88:   00007f3db12437f0 0000000000000020
0x00000000416b2e98:   0000000000008000 00007f3db1564748
0x00000000416b2ea8:   00000000ffffffff 00000000416b2ed0
0x00000000416b2eb8:   00007f3db12433f4 00007f3db1651340
0x00000000416b2ec8:   00000000416b3047 00000000416b2ee0
0x00000000416b2ed8:   00007f3db12432e7 00000000416b2ef0
0x00000000416b2ee8:   00007f3db1003a92 00000000416b3030
0x00000000416b2ef8:   00007f3db133a090 0000000000000000
0x00000000416b2f08:   00007f3db201ec68 00000000416b30a0
0x00000000416b2f18:   00000000416b2ff0 00000000a8428197
0x00000000416b2f28:   00000000416b3068 0000000000000000
0x00000000416b2f38:   00007f3db1e0d262 0000000000000000
0x00000000416b2f48:   00007f3db1f0e1b0 0000000000000005
0x00000000416b2f58:   0000000000000000 0000000000000001
0x00000000416b2f68:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00000000416b2f78:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00000000416b2f88:   0000000000000000 0000000100000000
0x00000000416b2f98:   00007f3db1f0e1b0 00007f3db201ec68
0x00000000416b2fa8:   00000000416b30d0 00007f3db201e908
0x00000000416b2fb8:   00007f3db1bebc21 0000000000010100
0x00000000416b2fc8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00000000416b2fd8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00000000416b2fe8:   000000004010bcc0 0000000000000001
0x00000000416b2ff8:   0000013b79197cd6 0000000000000000
0x00000000416b3008:   00007f3db1559b7c 00007f3db1559b78
0x00000000416b3018:   00000000ffffffff 00000000416b30e0
0x00000000416b3028:   00000000416b30e8 00000000416b3070
0x00000000416b3038:   00007f3db1082f20 0100000000000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x00007f3db170885b)
0x00007f3db170884b:   64 0f 1f 40 00 4d 8d 40 80 49 81 f8 80 00 00 00
0x00007f3db170885b:   66 0f 7f 07 66 0f 7f 47 10 66 0f 7f 47 20 66 0f 

Stack: [0x00000000415b3000,0x00000000416b4000],  sp=0x00000000416b2e48,  free space=1023k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libc.so.6+0x7b85b]  memset+0xa5b
V  [libjvm.so+0x5317f0]
V  [libjvm.so+0x5313f4]
V  [libjvm.so+0x5312e7]
V  [libjvm.so+0x2f1a92]
V  [libjvm.so+0x628090]
V  [libjvm.so+0x370f20]


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

VM state:not at safepoint (not fully initialized)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Dynamic libraries:
40000000-40009000 r-xp 00000000 fe:282 116003                            /usr/java/jre1.6.0_07/bin/java
40108000-4010a000 rwxp 00008000 fe:282 116003                            /usr/java/jre1.6.0_07/bin/java
4010a000-4012b000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
415b3000-415b4000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
415b4000-416b4000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f3db0358000-7f3db0362000 r-xp 00000000 fe:282 178514                    /lib64/libnss_files-2.5.so
7f3db0362000-7f3db0561000 ---p 0000a000 fe:282 178514                    /lib64/libnss_files-2.5.so
7f3db0561000-7f3db0563000 rwxp 00009000 fe:282 178514                    /lib64/libnss_files-2.5.so
7f3db0563000-7f3db0578000 r-xp 00000000 fe:282 178468                    /lib64/libnsl-2.5.so
7f3db0578000-7f3db0777000 ---p 00015000 fe:282 178468                    /lib64/libnsl-2.5.so
7f3db0777000-7f3db0779000 rwxp 00014000 fe:282 178468                    /lib64/libnsl-2.5.so
7f3db0779000-7f3db077b000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f3db077b000-7f3db0782000 r-xp 00000000 fe:282 130335                    /usr/java/jre1.6.0_07/lib/amd64/native_threads/libhpi.so
7f3db0782000-7f3db0883000 ---p 00007000 fe:282 130335                    /usr/java/jre1.6.0_07/lib/amd64/native_threads/libhpi.so
7f3db0883000-7f3db0885000 rwxp 00008000 fe:282 130335                    /usr/java/jre1.6.0_07/lib/amd64/native_threads/libhpi.so
7f3db0885000-7f3db0886000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f3db0886000-7f3db088d000 r-xp 00000000 fe:282 178540                    /lib64/librt-2.5.so
7f3db088d000-7f3db0a8d000 ---p 00007000 fe:282 178540                    /lib64/librt-2.5.so
7f3db0a8d000-7f3db0a8f000 rwxp 00007000 fe:282 178540                    /lib64/librt-2.5.so
7f3db0a8f000-7f3db0b11000 r-xp 00000000 fe:282 178524                    /lib64/libm-2.5.so
7f3db0b11000-7f3db0d10000 ---p 00082000 fe:282 178524                    /lib64/libm-2.5.so
7f3db0d10000-7f3db0d12000 rwxp 00081000 fe:282 178524                    /lib64/libm-2.5.so
7f3db0d12000-7f3db1407000 r-xp 00000000 fe:282 130305                    /usr/java/jre1.6.0_07/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
7f3db1407000-7f3db1506000 ---p 006f5000 fe:282 130305                    /usr/java/jre1.6.0_07/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
7f3db1506000-7f3db1650000 rwxp 006f4000 fe:282 130305                    /usr/java/jre1.6.0_07/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
7f3db1650000-7f3db168d000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f3db168d000-7f3db17db000 r-xp 00000000 fe:282 178494                    /lib64/libc-2.5.so
7f3db17db000-7f3db19db000 ---p 0014e000 fe:282 178494                    /lib64/libc-2.5.so
7f3db19db000-7f3db19de000 r-xp 0014e000 fe:282 178494                    /lib64/libc-2.5.so
7f3db19de000-7f3db19e0000 rwxp 00151000 fe:282 178494                    /lib64/libc-2.5.so
7f3db19e0000-7f3db19e5000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f3db19e5000-7f3db19e7000 r-xp 00000000 fe:282 178520                    /lib64/libdl-2.5.so
7f3db19e7000-7f3db1be7000 ---p 00002000 fe:282 178520                    /lib64/libdl-2.5.so
7f3db1be7000-7f3db1be9000 rwxp 00002000 fe:282 178520                    /lib64/libdl-2.5.so
7f3db1be9000-7f3db1bff000 r-xp 00000000 fe:282 178573                    /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so
7f3db1bff000-7f3db1dfe000 ---p 00016000 fe:282 178573                    /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so
7f3db1dfe000-7f3db1dff000 r-xp 00015000 fe:282 178573                    /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so
7f3db1dff000-7f3db1e00000 rwxp 00016000 fe:282 178573                    /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so
7f3db1e00000-7f3db1e04000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f3db1e04000-7f3db1e20000 r-xp 00000000 fe:282 178474                    /lib64/ld-2.5.so
7f3db1f05000-7f3db1f0d000 rwxs 00000000 00:0f 25408283                   /tmp/hsperfdata_root/6503
7f3db1f0d000-7f3db1f0f000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f3db1f0f000-7f3db1f16000 r-xp 00000000 fe:282 130339                    /usr/java/jre1.6.0_07/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
7f3db1f16000-7f3db2017000 ---p 00007000 fe:282 130339                    /usr/java/jre1.6.0_07/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
7f3db2017000-7f3db2019000 rwxp 00008000 fe:282 130339                    /usr/java/jre1.6.0_07/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
7f3db2019000-7f3db201a000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f3db201c000-7f3db201d000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f3db201d000-7f3db201e000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f3db201e000-7f3db2020000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f3db2020000-7f3db2022000 rwxp 0001c000 fe:282 178474                    /lib64/ld-2.5.so
7fffe5cde000-7fffe5cf3000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fffe5cf4000-7fffe5cf5000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xmx256M 
java_command: com.abcdef.npm.vmware.SnapshotVolume --snapshotremove --snapshotprefix ESX-hourly- --snapshotsuffix 2012-12-07::22:00:00.000 --username Administrator --password Nim123Boli --server vcenter.abcdef.com --sid de8ad27e --volume labvm6 --volume blabvmmgr --volume labvm4 --volume labvm2 --volume labvm7 --volume labvm --volume vmtemplates --volume labvm8 --volume labvm3
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=/abc/usr/bin:/abc/bin:/abc/utils:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/java/jre1.6.0_07/lib/amd64/server:/usr/java/jre1.6.0_07/lib/amd64:/usr/java/jre1.6.0_07/../lib/amd64
SHELL=/bin/sh

Signal Handlers:
SIGSEGV: [libjvm.so+0x661750], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGBUS: [libjvm.so+0x661750], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGFPE: [libjvm.so+0x504550], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGPIPE: [libjvm.so+0x504550], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGXFSZ: [libjvm.so+0x504550], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGILL: [libjvm.so+0x504550], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGUSR1: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGUSR2: [libjvm.so+0x5067c0], sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGHUP: SIG_IGN, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGINT: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGTERM: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGQUIT: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000


---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:Linux
uname:Linux 2.6.30.2-32259-opt #1 SMP Wed Nov 21 10:59:40 PST 2012 x86_64
libc:glibc 2.5 NPTL 2.5 
rlimit: STACK 2048k, CORE infinity, NPROC 106496, NOFILE 1024, AS 1843200k
load average:2.59 2.52 2.45

CPU:total 4 

Memory: 4k page, physical 12254804k(169936k free), swap 0k(0k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (10.0-b23) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.6.0_07-b06), built on Jun 10 2008 01:53:27 by "java_re" with gcc 3.2.2 (SuSE Linux)

time: Fri Dec  7 22:00:11 2012
elapsed time: 0 seconds
```

Comment: How does this vm start? From command line? Are you starting a server of some kind or just trying to run a simple program? Other than that, the line with `swap 0k(0k free)` might be something you want to check

Comment: it's started from a shell script. It's a simple program and not a server.

Comment: It looks like you are running this on top of some sort of virtualization software (VMWare?). Can you confirm ?May be this java binary is incompatible with your OS with virtualization turned on?

Answer (score 6):

The SIGBUS (0x7) memset thing is most often a /tmp directory full issue.  This duplicates the answer already given.  However, I would like to add more information on what to do when you encounter it.

If you have access to /tmp directory, free some content and rerun.  Your problem should be fixed.

Quite often, you may not have permission to fiddle with the /tmp directory.  In that case, you workaround is

```
java -Djava.io.tmpdir=/export/home/me/mytmp
```

where you put in a path to a directory you do have access to if you have control over where and how the java command is issued.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on one of my machines. Turn out the problem was with the disk space. You need to check the root partition probably. / directory.
I read somewhere that SIGBUS signal is usually raised when /tmp directory is full and JVM is unable to access that area.
Usually java writes some hotspot reports in the /tmp directory.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually due to either a bug in one of your system libraries, a corrupted executable, or bad RAM. I recommend running [memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/) to check your RAM; if it's okay, then use your distribution's package manager to verify the package contents for Java and glibc.